# Calculating a minimum in object arrays and then using it in another calculation

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to understand how to take an object array that contains objects that have a name and 4 numbers and finding the lowest test grade. I have this Student object that has a name, bonus points earned, test 1 grade, test 2 grade, and a test 3 grade. I need to make sure that all 3 test grades added together don't go over 300 points.

I then need to find the lowest test grade of the 3 entered grades for each student and then be able to add the bonus points to them and print out the new grade.

I was going to create a method to loop through the Student object array and find the lowest grade for each student, have it create a new array with just the lowest grades and add that to the bonus points earned for each student but I'm not actually sure how to go about doing that part. This is the code for the Student object I've created so far:

```
public class Student
{
   private String name;
   private int bonusPoints;
   private int test1;
   private int test2;
   private int test3;
   public static final int MAX_TOTAL = 300;

   public Student(String n, int bP, int g1, int g2, int g3)
   {
      setName(n);
      setBonus(bP);
      setTest1(g1);
      setTest2(g2);
      setTest3(g3);
   }

    //Setters & getters

   //Method to check total of all 3 test grades
   public boolean checkTotal(Student[] array)
   {
      int total = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      {
         total += //I'm not sure how to refer to test1 ,test2, and test3 here
      }
      if (total > MAX_TOTAL)
      {
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         return true;
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So in order to add the 3 test totals together and check if it exceeds a maximum value. I would do something like this.

```
public boolean checkTotal()
{
 int total = this.test1 + this.test2 + this.test3;
 return total > MAX_TOTAL;
}
```

When referring to a classes variables within that class you can use the 'this' keyword to refer to the current instance of that class.
So a method call of that object would look something like this:

```
Student studentOne = new Student("Foo",90,80,70,10);
if(!studentOne.checkTotal())
 //do something
else
 //do something else
```

Also when returning a boolean you don't need an if/else most of the time. You can simply put

```
return /*your boolean expression here*/;
```

Comment: Ohhh I think I was over-complicating it cause I was trying to pass in the whole object array and do calculations with that and ended up confusing myself. Thank you so much for your help !